# Netbeans MySQL connection : Server properties error

Tags: mysql, lamp, 19.04, phpmyadmin, netbeans

I am working on `Netbeans-11.0` with `JDK12` on `Ubuntu 19.04`. I have `LAMP server` with which I use `phpMyAdmin` to connect to MySQL server. Now I am trying to connect Netbeans to MySQL server but it shows an error. Please help me..

Error message : ***null, message from server: "Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL sever"***

[image: Click for Image]

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44871109/10785056)

Comment: You can add what worked as an answer and cite the source.